# Obtain INSERT statements as a query result

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Using pgAdmin on my local machine, I am able to view table data and also export the INSERT statements for the table using "backup" button (Plain format, Use column inserts, Use Insert commands).

But when I connect using pgAdmin to another environment using the browser then the pgAdmin is probably running in server mode so my local file system is not visible in pgAdmin Storage manager. When I click backup then the file size is also displayed always as 0 bytes in pgAdmin Storage manager.

Is it possible to formulate my query in such a way that I get the insert queries as the result. Then I dont need to go to storage manager of the remote pgAdmin.

Comment: https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/import_export_data.html

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se. If you have any supplementary information, please put it in with the question (use the edit link) and try to avoid having relevant data/info in comments - we like a good [single source of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth)... help us to help you!